# Get account ID of connected stripe account

Tags: accounts, stripe-connect

When I run a test for connecting a user to accept payments through my application, I will need the account id to charge their account.

```
Stripe\Token::create(
array("customer" => CUSTOMER_ID, "card" => CARD_ID),
array("stripe_account" => CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID) // id of the connected account
);
```

In this snippet (from Stripe), the `CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID` implies the connecting about id which starts with acct_

How do I obtain this ?

Thanks,
Rich.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I found what I needed.

Comment: can u tell me how u just get that key.[CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID]..please tell the step.

Comment: You get it when you connect another user account. When a user connects to your application, their Stripe account is passed to your app, which you want to save to payout.

Comment: ok, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

I came here from a Google search with a similar issue.  It is actually easy to get from the OAUTH flow, the documentation just does not make it clear which field it is.  In short, the missing link is that the `CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID` is the `stripe_user_id` that you get at the end of the OAUTH flow when the account is connected as per https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts

In their example response at the end of the flow

```
{
"token_type": "bearer",
"stripe_publishable_key": PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
"scope": "read_write",
"livemode": false,
"stripe_user_id": USER_ID,  //this is it
"refresh_token": REFRESH_TOKEN,
"access_token": ACCESS_TOKEN
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Anil..I will outline the steps here:

Step 1: Find client id of your platform. This you can obtain from your settings
Step 2: Set a redirect URI. This will be where your users are redirected to after they have signed up for Stripe
Step3: Add a Connect Button by which leads to connect authorize_url endpoint

Find more details here:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts#oauth-flow

Comment: The way to get your connected user's account Id is to extract the user ID from the StripeOAuthToken. What is confusing is StripeUserID = AccountID