# Test mode of stripe :: CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

From where can I get the **CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID**

Can anyone help me with the steps to obtain the same for the test mode of stripe?

Comment: Do you mean the ID some kind of account(bank account)? 
I don't understand what you mean CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400085/get-account-id-of-connected-stripe-account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the ID of the connected account that you want to perform operations on. It should be in the format `acct_12345`. You can find it in your dashboard:

1. Go to https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/connect/accounts/overview
2. Click on the account you want
3. The account ID is in the top right